# 500 Internal Server error when trying to pass messages between SignalR self-hosted server and client

Tags: c#, mono, signalr

I'm trying to work up a simple example of a SignalR self hosted server on a Mono solution to demo to our executive department. I've followed the github example code, and I have half of the functionality working. When the 'broadcast' button is pushed, the message in the text box is echoed in the server console, but it does not get broadcast back to the client.

The server code:

```cs
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Initialize your application
            new AppHost().Init();

            WebApplication.Start<Startup>("http://127.0.0.1:10000");
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object src, EventArgs e)
        { 
            this.Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept,origin,authorization,content-type");

            #if DEBUG
            Profiler.Start();
            #endif
        }

        protected void Application_EndRequest(object src, EventArgs e)
        {
            #if DEBUG
            Profiler.Stop();
            #endif
        }
    }

    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true });
        }
    }

    public class Chat : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Clients.All.addMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

The client code:

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--  If this is an MVC project then use the following -->
<!--  <script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:10000/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.connection.hub.url = "http://127.0.0.1:10000/signalr";
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;

        // Proxy created on the fly          
        var chat = $.connection.chat;

        // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it          
        chat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
        $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
        };

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start({ jsonp: true }).done(function() {
            $("#broadcast").click(function () {
                // Call the chat method on the server
                    chat.server.send($('#msg').val());
            });
        });
    });
</script>

  <div>
    <input type="text" id="msg" />
    <input type="button" id="broadcast" value="broadcast" />

    <ul id="messages">
    </ul>
  </div>
```

When I start the client up, I do get a strange error in the negotiation process, which seems strange since the client can successfully push messages to the server.

```
[17:13:54 GMT-0400 (EDT)] SignalR: Auto detected cross domain url. jquery.signalR.min.js:10
[17:13:54 GMT-0400 (EDT)] SignalR: Negotiating with 'http://127.0.0.1:10000/signalr/negotiate'. jquery.signalR.min.js:10
[17:13:54 GMT-0400 (EDT)] SignalR: SignalR: Initializing long polling connection with server. jquery.signalR.min.js:10
[17:13:54 GMT-0400 (EDT)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to 'http://127.0.0.1:10000/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&connectionToke…kjVpNzqCLDXzDDRkE&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chat%22%7D%5D&tid=2' using longPolling. jquery.signalR.min.js:10
GET http://127.0.0.1:10000/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&connectionToke…D&tid=2&callback=jQuery191021586751635186374_1366665233871&_=1366665233874 500 (Internal   Server Error) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
send jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
b.extend.ajax jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
s jquery.signalR.min.js:10
(anonymous function) jquery.signalR.min.js:10
[17:13:54 GMT-0400 (EDT)] SignalR: Longpolling connected
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.